# Configuring HAPROXY for Vaadin 14 application with PUSH

Tags: vaadin, haproxy, high-availability, vaadin-flow

I am trying to configure a Vaadin 14 application behind haproxy.
I have configured haproxy for sticky sessions, however, it doesn't seem to work for me.
I am using spring-security in the application to login as well.

This is a snippet of my haproxy.cfg. It works for simple applications.

```
listen tomcat-servers
bind proxy-server:8443
mode tcp
option tcp-check
balance roundrobin
cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache
server tc1 tomcat-server-1:8444 check cookie tc1
server tc2 tomcat-server-2:8444 check cookie tc2
```

Would anyone have an experience of this as I would like to be able to deploy the vaadin application on several servers?

I don't care about session replication across the servers. If a server goes down any users sessions on that server can re-login. I just want to be able to spread the load around to different servers.

Thanks for any help,
John.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work for me" **what** does not work? The push? The sticky sessions? Spring-security?

Comment: I get the login screen and enter the login details and then it looks like it is just about to login in and I get the login screen again. I think it is the sticky sessions that is the problem as monitoring the applications on the tomcat servers, one server starts off handling the login and then activity kicks off on the other server even though there are no other users of the application.

Comment: The behavior that you are describing is exactly what happens with a Vaadin 10+ cluster without sticky sessions. Try using `cookie SRVNAME insert` instead of using the JSESSIONID.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have looked into this a bit more and I think the problem Ihave is that I am using https (mode tcp) all the way to the tomcat servers so haproxy cannot access the traffic to modify the JSESSIONID or insert other cookies- which I guess makes sense. I think the way to set this up is to do the SSL decryption on the haproxy server and use http to the backend tomcat servers. I think you can also decrypt on the haproxy server and re-encrypt again going to the backend tomcat servers.